# Suppose $f(s)=(e^{2\pi is}, 1)$, $p(s)=(1, s)$, and $h(s)=(e^{2\pi is}, s)$; then are $p\ast f\ast\bar{p}$ and $h\ast f\ast\bar{h}$ path homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

**The Problem**: Suppose $I=[0, 1]$, $1\in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$, $f, g, h: I\to S^1\times I$ are paths defined by $f(s)=(e^{2\pi is}, 1)$, $p(s)=(1, s)$, and $h(s)=(e^{2\pi is}, s)$. Are $p\ast f\ast\bar{p}$ and $h\ast f\ast\bar{h}$ path homotopic? Here $g\ast k$ denotes the path $$\sigma(s)=
\begin{cases}
g(2s), s\in[0, 1/2] \\[2ex]
k(2s-1), s\in[1/2, 1]
\end{cases}$$, and $\bar{g}(s)$ denotes the path $g(1-s)$.

**My Attempt**: I tried to establish the straight-line homotopy, which failed because the points would not all be contained in $S^1\times I$. Then I tried to show that they are not homotopic, by assuming that $p\ast f\ast\bar{p}$ is path homotopic to $h\ast f\ast\bar{h}$ and tried to deduce a contradiction, also to no avail. Now I am stuck-any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $S^1\times I$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Comment: @YuqiaoHuang Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

At the meeting point between $f$ and $\overline{p},\overline{h}$ respectively  gives $1 = f(4s-1) = p(1-4s)$ and $1 = f(4s-1) = h(1-4s)$ at $s = 1/4$.
and meeting point between $f$ and $p,h$ respectively gives,
$1 = f(4s-1) = p(2s-1)$, $1 = f(4s-1) = h(2s-1)$ at $s = 1/2$.

You need to come up with homotopy between $p$ and $h$ which satisfies the above boundary conditions.

Let $h(s)=(h_1(s),h_2(s))$, $f(s)=(f_1(s),f_2(s))$, $p(s) = (p_1(s),p_2(s))$.

Try Homotopy:
For $0 \leq s\leq 1/4$,
$$F(s,t) = (h_1(1-4s)e^{-j 2\pi ((1-4s)t+(1-t)))},h_2(1-4s)).$$

For $1/4 \leq s\leq 1/2$,
$$F(s,t) = (f_1(4s-1)e^{-j 2\pi (1-t)},f_2(4s-1)).$$

For $1/2 \leq s\leq 1$,
$$F(s,t) = (h_1(2s-1)e^{-j 2\pi ((2s-1)t+(1-t)))},p_2(2s-1)).$$